# Ajax увеличение значения тв modx

Tags: javascript, ajax, modx

Создал два тв greenButton и redButton — числа, при нажатии на кноку сделать их увеличение на +1

только что-то не работает, я так понял ajax скрипт но не пойму почему

```
<button class="btn green"  data-btntype="greenButton">like
  [[!+modx.user.id:memberof=`Administrator`:then=`([[*greenButton]])`:else=``]]
  </button>

<button class="btn red"
  data-btntype="redButton">dlike
  [[!+modx.user.id:memberof=`Administrator`:then=`([[*redButton]])`:else=``]]
  </button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '[[*uri]]',
        data:'&action=countButton&but='
          +$(this).attr('data-btntype'),
        success: function(msg){
          msg = JSON.parse(msg);
          window.location.href = msg.url;
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

сниппет ajax

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') {return;}
$action = $_POST['action'];
if (empty($action)) {return;}
$res = '';
echo $_POST['action'];
switch ($action) {
  case 'countButton':
    $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $modx->resource->id);
    // Получаем предыдущее значение счетчика
    $count = $resource->getTVValue($_POST['but']) + 1;
    // Устанавливаем новое значение
    $resource->setTVValue($_POST['but'],$count);
    $resource->save();
    // Очищаем кеш ресурса, чтобы изменения отобразились сразу
    $resource->_contextKey = $resource->get('context_key');
    $cache = $modx->cacheManager->getCacheProvider(
             $modx->getOption('cache_resource_key', null, 'resource'));
    $key = $resource->getCacheKey();
    $cache->delete($key, array('deleteTop' => true));
    $cache->delete($key);
    // Возвращаем URL, по которому нужно отправить пользователя
    $res = $modx->toJSON(array('url' => $_POST['url']));
}
if (!empty($res)) {
  die($res);
}
```

Comment: Какие ошибки? Что именно не работает? Какой результат вы ожидаете увидеть?

Comment: в сниппете вывожу echo $_POST['action']; и ничего не происходит, он просто не вызывается аяксом